# Chartjs time plot xAxis shows year 1970

Tags: javascript, plot, time-series, chart.js

I am trying to plot a series of measurements (indexed by timestamps). When I try to plot example date the xaxis ranges from 1970 until 2018, although the data only exists in 2018-12.

What setting does scale the xaxis correctly?

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("plot").getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ["Value"],
            datasets: [{
                'label': 'Value',
                'data': [
                    {t: '2018-12-01T12:00:00', y: 100},
                    {t: '2018-12-02T12:00:00', y: 90},
                    {t: '2018-12-03T12:00:00', y: 85},
                    {t: '2018-12-04T12:00:00', y: 86},
                    {t: '2018-12-05T12:00:00', y: 77},
                    {t: '2018-12-06T12:00:00', y: 73},
                    {t: '2018-12-07T12:00:00', y: 72},
                    {t: '2018-12-08T12:00:00', y: 70},
                    {t: '2018-12-15T12:00:00', y: 71},
                    {t: '2018-12-16T12:00:00', y: 72},
                    {t: '2018-12-17T12:00:00', y: 69},
                    ],
                'fill': false,
            }],
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'foobar',
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'time',
                    display: true,
                    time: {
                        parser: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss",
                    },
                }]
            },
        },
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
type: 'time',
display: true,
time: {
    parser: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss",
},
```

You can add in scale > xAxes > time according to [ChartJS](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html?h=time) And you can use also add time format of [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/)

```
type: 'time',
display: true,
distribution: 'series',
time: {
    unit:"year",
    displayFormats:{year:'YYYY'},
    min:'1970' ,
    max:'2018',
}
```

Comment: The option "distribution: 'series'" does not work, since I have irregularly spaced measurements. When using this option, the scaling of the data seems much better, BUT the spacing in between the measurements is inconsistant. Sadly, this is no solution.

Comment: you can change `distribution: 'linear'` or you add your complete code as example in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/pen/) or similar to help me to find the right solution

Comment: I used `options.scales.xAxes.time` with same props you said and it's working on chartjs 2.9.3

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help you, but when I tried to add a date "2017/02/29", the x-axis also goes back to 1970, because there were only 28 days in Feb 2017!